# What happens to the nucleus energy when it decays?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, proton-decay

When an atom decays into another atom, what happens to the potential energy of the nucleus ?

I think it will get more negative because, in general, through fission and fusion an atom tries to get a greater binding energy and this means it has more potential energy stored. In this way the walls of the potential well get higher and it is harder for a nucleon to leave the nucleus. That makes the nucleus more stable.

is this true ?